# How to change border-style to none in <lightning-input> LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system

I am trying to change the border style to none of a LWC Lightning-input tag. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom class for your `lightning-input`

```html
<lightning-input class="input-no-border" ... >
```

Add below css for your custom class

```css
.input-no-border {
    --lwc-shadowButtonFocus: 0;
    --lwc-borderWidthThin: 0;
    --slds-c-input-shadow-focus: 0;
    --sds-c-input-shadow-focus: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. It worked.